# Change the date in the form using moment.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, momentjs

I have an edit form. Currently, i can fetch the inputed title and description. Here is the code

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    console.log(newProps);
    console.log(newProps.calendarEvent);
    const { change, calendarEvent } = this.props;
    if (this.state.initial) {
      this.setState({ initial: false }, () => {
        if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.calendarEvent.summary) {
          change('title', newProps.calendarEvent.summary);
        }

        if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.calendarEvent.description) {
          change('description', newProps.calendarEvent.description);
        }
```

Due to that code, how can i fetch the inputed time using moment.js

Comment: Where do you store your inputted time?

Comment: @DipeshWagle it’s in calendarEvrnt.start.dateTime

Comment: Do you have a moment imported and can you show me the sample value of calendarEvent.start.dateTime ?

Comment: @DipeshWagle The moment is imported. Here is example that is in the console
2018-12-03T08:00:00+02:00

In the form i can see only the title input and description. I need th fetch the am/pm, minutes and hours

Answer (score 0):

If you have the DateTime in calendarEvent.start.dateTime you can first convert it into moment object

```
moment(calendarEvent.start.dateTime)
```

Then you can use it as any moment object. If you need to get the time in minutes hours AM/PM format you can do

```
moment(calendarEvent.start.dateTime).format('hh:mm A')
```

Comment: What's wrong with that, can you help?

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
 if (this.state.initial) {
      this.setState({ initial: false }, () => {
 if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.moment(calendarEvent.start.dateTime)) {
          change('time', newProps.moment(calendarEvent.start.dateTime).format('hh:mm A'));
        }
}

Comment: Can you edit and post the full source code of the Component, so it would be easier?

Answer (score 0):

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    console.log(newProps);
    console.log(newProps.calendarEvent);
    const { change, calendarEvent } = this.props;
    if (this.state.initial) {
      this.setState({ initial: false }, () => {
        if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.calendarEvent.summary) {
          change('title', newProps.calendarEvent.summary);
        }

        if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.calendarEvent.description) {
          change('description', newProps.calendarEvent.description);
        }

        if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.moment(calendarEvent.start.dateTime)) {
          change('hour', newProps.moment(calendarEvent.start.dateTime).format('hh:mm A'));
        }
      });
    }
  }
```